# 301 redirect works in browser but gives status 200

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I added an ssl cert and want to have https only. In browser http requests are forwarded to https, but curl -I http://www.domain.com returns HTTP/1.1 200 OK.
Afaik googlebot will see status 200, too, but has to see it's moved permanently. 
Is .htaccess wrong?

WHM 60 (B35), CentOS 7.3, Wordpress

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; preload; includeSubDomains" env=HTTPS

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out code below returns domain, folders and files with 301

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```